# How to dynamically populate a div with data from an AJAX result (JSON)?

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'MyServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "nodeid": componentNodeId,
        "optype": OpType
    },
    success: function (data) {

        $.each(data, function (key, value) {

            childId = value.ChildNodeId;
            deviceValue = value.DeviceValue;
            count++;
        });
    }
});
$("#myModalBody").empty(); 
$("#myModalBody").text(childId);  // this displays only one childId eg. "John" 
$("#myModalRead").modal('show');
```

but i
 want each json object in a new line inside the modal body

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRead" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
               </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

suppose I have a `JSON` array like

```
"data": [{
    "childId": "John",
    "value": "23"
}, {
    "childId": "gay",
    "value": "56"
}, {
    "childId": "harry",
    "value": "78"
}, ]
```

I want to display them as
 John : 23
 gay : 56
 harry : 78
 in the modal body in javascript.**Each object in a new line**.how can i do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your modal `div` has an ID of `modal` you can add this to your `.each()`block -

```
$("#modal").append($("<p>").text(value.childId + ": " + value.value));
```

**Edit**

A more complete answer based on your updated question.

Your HTML (note I've not actually made any changes here) -

```
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRead" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
          <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
            <div class="modal-content">
              <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
              </div>
              <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
               </div>
              <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

The updated javascript should look like this -

```
$.ajax({
    async: false,
    url: 'MyServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    data: {
        "nodeid": componentNodeId,
        "optype": OpType
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $("#myModalBody").empty();
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $("#myModalBody").append($("<p>").text(value.childId + ": " + value.value));
            /* If you're re-using these variables you can uncomment these lines 
            childId = value.ChildNodeId;
            deviceValue = value.DeviceValue;  
            count++; 
            */                          
        });
        $("#myModalRead").modal('show');
    }
});
/* The following are no longer required as we've handled it in the success function
of the ajax call
$("#myModalBody").empty(); 
$("#myModalBody").text(childId);  // this displays only one childId eg. "John" 
$("#myModalRead").modal('show');
*/
```

**And a "working" (a.k.a. no ajax) sample -**

```js
var data = [{
  "childId": "John",
  "value": "23"
}, {
  "childId": "gay",
  "value": "56"
}, {
  "childId": "harry",
  "value": "78"
}];

$.each(data, function(key, value) {
  $("#myModalBody").append($("<p>").text(value.childId + ": " + value.value));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade" id="myModalRead" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
        </button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel"></h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody">
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what is the use of ("<p>") here? do i ave to add it in my html?

Comment: @PrernaSingh no the `$("<p>")` statement creates and adds a new paragraph (`p`) element to your html dynamically.

Comment: can u share the html for this?

Comment: <div class="modal-body" id="myModalBody></div>

Comment: @PrernaSingh I've updated my answer, take a look.  I'll add a basic working demo (without ajax) in a minute.

Comment: @PrernaSingh Ok, I've added a demo version to show the code in action.

Answer (score 1):

Sample :

```js
var el = $('#dbg');
var data = [{
  "childId": "John",
  "value": "23"
}, {
  "childId": "gay",
  "value": "56"
}, {
  "childId": "harry",
  "value": "78"
}];

var html = '';

$.each(data, function(key, value) {


  html += "<div> id : " + value.childId + " => " + value.value + "</div>"

});

el.html(html);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dbg'></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just append it in `$.each loop`

```
var childId="";
var deviceValue="";
$.each(data, function (key, value) {
    childId = value.childId; //get child Id
    deviceValue = value.value; //get value
    $('#yourmodalId .modal-body').append('<p><div class="cid">Child ID='+childId+' and Device Value='+deviceValue+'</div></p>');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Some of the things to notice:

```
$.ajax({
    //async: false, // <-----bad idea to have it set to false.
    url: 'MyServlet',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType:"json", // <----As the response seems to be json so add this
    data: {
        "nodeid": componentNodeId,
        "optype": OpType
    },
    success: function (data) {
        $.each(data, function (key, value) {
            $('targetElem').append($("<p>", {text: value.childId + " : " + value.value}));
        });
    }
});
```

`dataType:"json"` should be added in the options as above or you need to have your data to be parsed before you use it in the `$.each` loop with `JSON.parse()`, it parses the json string to a valid json.

Answer (score 0):

Try these:

```
$.ajax({
async: false,
url: 'MyServlet',
type: 'POST',
data: {
    "nodeid": componentNodeId,
    "optype": OpType
},
success: function (data) {
      render(data);
}
});

function render(data){
     $('#myModalBody').remove(); // to remove previosly data
     $('#myModalBody').append('<table><tbody>');
     $.each(data, function (index, value) {
         var rowT = "<tr>" +
                  "<td>" + value.ChildId+ 
                  "</td>" +
                   "<td>" + value.value+ 
                 " </td>" +
                    "</tr>"
    $('#myModalBody tbody').append(rowT);
    $('#myModalBody').append('</tbody></table>');
});
}
```